# No displacement on imported OBJ

Tags: texturing, import, displacement, procedural

I created a procedural fabric texture. The fabric texture works fine on all objects created inside blender, but if I import an OBJ (created with c4d) and apply the texture to it I cannot see any of the displacement detail. The UVs are lined up perfectly and I can see the translucency channel from the principled shader, but I cannot see any displacement on the imported mesh.

I can recreate the mesh in Blender no problem and the displacement shows up just fine, but I need to import a lot of objects from c4D and I need to figure out what is causing the issue.

Can you think of any property that an imported mesh has that a blender created mesh doesn't have?

Comment: Did you enable displacement in material settings and render settings properly? Does your C4D objects have enough geometry for the displacement to work?

Comment: I have the material working on a plane in the same scene. The plane has 0 subdivisions, so it's basically a quad, but the detail shows up just fine on it. The material is the same as the material on the imported mesh, so the material settings are identical. As for the render settings, both the working plane and the non-working imported mesh are in the same scene, so the render settings are identical. What other factors are there to consider?